# Only do work on the first page load, not when the user comes via back/foward

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do some work when the user first lands on my page (via a link or directly entering the URL). However, if the user goes off somewhere else and comes back to my page via back/forward buttons, I don't want to do the work again.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Note: The work should be done if the user hits the refresh button, forcing a page reload.

Comment: By back/forward do you mean back/forward in browser history? Cuz if so, this is not possible to detect through Javascript.

Comment: You could store a some kinda flag in localstorage. Thats all I can think of...

Comment: @HenrikAmmer, I have clarified the question. I am hoping there might be some way to achieve this.

Comment: @elclanrs, I considered setting a nonce cookie but I would need to involve the server to embed the nonce cookie within the page first so the JS knows that nonce has already been set once for this particular instance of the page. This would work because navigating to a page in history would not trigger a fresh server request and allow me to determine if the page has been loaded from browser memory.

Comment: But if the navigation in history does not trigger a request, how will the cookies exist/notexist differ? Will it not be cached along with everything else? Or does the cookies always get refreshed?

Comment: No. Just... no. Reconsider your design.

Comment: @RyanKinal, it's an client-side MVC app that does a bit of model-binding work so this approach would come in handy to preserving the state of unsaved form fields which are stored in browser memory. The alternative is to show a warning to the user on unload if any of the form fields have been changed but not saved

Comment: @RyanKinal, where's the fun in that?  FWIW, in FF and possibly other browsers, window.onload event won't fire when the user navigates back through back/forward buttons. In Chrome, however, the event gets fired again. This means that any UI elements that were generated, get re-generated. The FF behaviour seems to be the more correct one. This is an artifact of the browser's bfcache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (performance.navigation.type !== performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
     //No back or forward button.
}
```

Combine this with localStorage I suppose.

Comment: this won't work on the destination page, only on the page the user is navigating away from.

Comment: @aleemb What do you mean? Works fine for me

Comment: Sorry hadn't noticed this was part of performance library. On testing, it works just fine in Chrome, as is, without having to use local storage.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is outlined below, albeit, it's not at all elegant.

1. embed a random nonce key in the server generated page
2. JS checks if this random nonce exists in cookie?

   1. If it doesn't exist, save it in a cookie and run the script
   2. If it exists, the page was loaded from browser memory and hence not a fresh load.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea:

browsers usually remember input-values, so they will be present when you navigate back.

You may use a input(hidden with CSS).

Onload check if the current value of the input does have a special value(this value must be generated on server-side, so it will not refresh when you use back/forward)

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    if($('#history').val()==$('#history').data('value'))
    {
      alert('you did use back/forward');
    }    
    else
    {
      $('#history').val($('#history').data('value'));
      alert('you did not use back/forward');
    }    
  }
);
</script>
<input style="display:none" id="history" data-value="<?php echo time();?>"/>
```

When the user uses back/forward, the input-value is equal to the data-value attribute(but not when the user hits F5, because then the data-value-attribute will refresh too).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use HTML5 web storage, Use session storage. When page loas first time check if local storage variable is set and stores some data, If not then set data, if user uses next/prev button and comes back again when pageload event will get called you can detect that user been here before and its not the first page load. See this demo
http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/html5-web-storage/web_storage.html and here is the detailed article http://www.amitpatil.me/introduction-to-html5-feature-web-storage/

Comment: this wouldn't work. user comes to the page, you store key 123 in storage. now user hits the refresh button, key 123 exists so you don't do the work but you really should because it was a refresh instead of a history navigation.

Comment: You are right, i didnt thought about this possibility :( There is another solution window.onbeforeunload = function () {} but that also fails on "refresh", Window refresh and back/next buttons call this function so i guess its not useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

[LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) would be nice here. Works similar to cookies but only exists on the client side, Nothing is sent with the headers. Others have said the same or similar, I hope this example shows you how easy it all is to do.

So you will set the value of the variable to the identifier for the current page and reference it against the variable A) existing, and B) being set to the first page.

```
<script>
if( !localStorage["lastPage"] && localStorage["lastPage"] != theFirstPageIdentifier ) {
   // this is the first view
   localStorage["lastPage"] = currentPageIdentifier;
}
</script>
```

Note: localStorage is not available by older version of IE (maybe others) and cookies could be used here for a fallback. Same concept.

I feel like you need an example to show you this will work: http://rlemon.github.com/demos/12323999/page1.html view source.

Comment: wouldn't work, same reason as given for the answer by @www.amitpatil.me

Comment: @aleemb I had uploaded a small demo for you - will alert on first page first view only. code can be modified to suit a number of different scenarios

Answer (score -1):

I think a solution to your problem would be storing a session cookie that will remain while the current browser is open , then will expire - this is easy using [jQuery Cookie Plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

Then you can set a cookie as easily as this

```
$.cookie("example", "foo");
```

The work you talk about would be performed if cookie is not present , and ignored is cookie is present

Comment: If the user refreshes the page manually on the page then the cookie would still be present and the work would not be performed. In that scenario the work should be performed because the user manually refreshed the page.

Comment: you could put a datetime in there and keep the page for set amount of time , I do not think there is a way in javascript or jquery to detect if the page is comming from back button and to detect if the page is being refreshed , on server-side code this is easier to accomplish